# Camera use confirmation

Tags: javascript, camera

I wan't to remove users choice when he is asked for allowing camera in browser if he don't allow it. Is there possibility of doing it, or to ask him again about it? I can't find a way of triggering it unless i refresh my page.

Comment: Your question lacks context, and previous attempts

Comment: So do you want to remove the choice? Or ask them again? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
        function initializeMedia() {
            if(!('mediaDevices' in navigator)) {
              navigator.mediaDevices = {};
            }

            if(!('getUserMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices)){
              //polyfil
              navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(constraints) {
                const getUserMedia =  navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                                    navigator.msGetUserMedia;

                if(!getUserMedia) {
                  return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented'))
                }

                return new Promise(resolve, reject => {
                  getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
                })
              }
            }

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then(stream => {
              videoPlayer.srcObject = stream;
              videoPlayer.style.display = "block";
            }).catch(err => console.log(err))

          }
this is method, i can catch it if it's not allowed, and inside i would tell to forget users choice of not allowing it. Or if there is another way to do that
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: No, you can't remove or suppress the choice the user has.

At least me (and I guess most other visitors) would instantly leave your page/app and never use it again if you would have the possibility to revoke the choices I as a user make on my own machine. And the chances for browser vendors to allow it are really really small, because users will stop using the browser if they'd allow it.

Almost the same goes for constantly asking the user over and over again. Most users simply won't visit your page ever again if you keep asking them. In case you are going to build some application, users most likely will stop using it.